# Android Show a dialog until a thread is done and then continue with the program

Tags: android, multithreading, listview

I am reading a few thousand items out of a database in my Android app and want to show a loading dialog,  start a thread and read the database then close the dialog and then populate a listview with the data. 
I cant seem to figure this out.

I have the dialog pop up and disappear but I don't know how to populate the listview after the thread is done.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an AsyncTask, populate the listview in onPostExecute().

http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746

```
private class InsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

  private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);

  // can use UI thread here
  protected void onPreExecute() {
     this.dialog.setMessage("Inserting data...");
     this.dialog.show();
  }
  // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
  protected Void doInBackground(final String... args) {
     //do something in background, i.e. loading data
     return null;
  }

  // can use UI thread here
  protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
     if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
     }
     // populate list here
  }
}
```

...

```
new InsertDataTask ().execute();
```

Also helpful:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: I am using your answer here to search for Location but the `ProgressDialog' appears very briefly and is dismissed immediately (almost like a flash). I want it to remain showing until the Location is found. Please advise me on how to do this.