# Get user location in AsyncTask

Tags: android, maps, android-asynctask, userlocation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Get Location Using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676653/how-to-get-location-using-asynctask)

im trying two days to get userlocation in asyncTask but i  can't.
i search all google but i cant find anything that can help.
can anyone help? if he had code or he know how to implement this thing.
thanx guys!

Comment: this can help you:  [How To Get Location Using AsyncTask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676653/how-to-get-location-using-asynctask)

Comment: i try it but still have problems.. :/

Answer (score 0):

getting the location doesn't require asyncTask . you ask to get locations events via a listener that will be called in the future , and that's it . the call is asynchronous anyway.

Comment: so why i cant get user location and my app dont run on ICS?

Comment: anyway , this seems like a nice sample : http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/ . haven't tested it , but it looks very similar to what i know that works .

Comment: when i was on Gingerbread the code worked fine. the problems started when i upgrade to ICS my phone

Comment: i see . sadly i don't have ICS currently .

Comment: i try to use salman code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676653/how-to-get-location-using-asynctask
but didnt work. for some reason i cant get the location so the only i see on screen is Loading.

Comment: did you also try the example i've written about? maybe google has posted some new changes about ICS regarding this topic that need your attention?

Comment: yeap but still tha same. i downgrade to 2.3 untill the presentation of the project. thanx for your time!

Comment: maybe it's the rom that you've installed that has the problems? have you tried a different one ? have you tried an app on the market that requires the gps ?