# Getting the most accurate GPS location

Tags: android, gps

How do I get my app to start updating GPS location as soon as I open it?

Right now I have this code:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider,0 ,0, loc_listener);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation (bestProvider);
```

Which takes the best location. I ran my app on my phone and it got the location from where I was earlier today.

I want my app to update the gps location when I first open it.

I have been looking at these threads:

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)
[Android find GPS location once, show loading dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486055/android-find-gps-location-once-show-loading-dialog)

But I am having trouble wiring everything up.

Comment: "Wiring everything up" as in wire the code into an interface or as in not using first `getLastKnownLocation`, but rather last known after sat lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you need to set up a listener and override the onLocationChanged method. That should get you your next GPS location ie the location after sat lock.

This tutorial should illustrate what i'm trying to say: http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2 .

Stop me if I'm wrong StackOverflow, I'm not sure of myself on this one.

Comment: well I got something to work and now I just need to get the GPS sensor to stop

Comment: unregister the listener when you are done, that should do it.

A usefull little something I learned recently here on stackoverflow:

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            locationManager.unregisterListener(listener);
        }
    }, theTimeInMilliseconds);

This will unregister the listener, but only do it after theTimeinMilliseconds milliseconds. Should complete your answer.